# Check brew and brew-cask for valid package names

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew

I have a iMac and Macbook for work and another set for home. I end up getting a new one every couple of years so I end up re-setting up everything atleast couple of times a year. So I wrote a script to automate as much as possible: https://github.com/pathikrit/mac-setup-script/blob/master/setup.sh

The only problem with above script is that there is no way for me to pre-check if a `brew` or a `brew-cask` package is still valid e.g. I want to something like `brew check foo` to make sure that brew still knows about foo. How do I do that?

Comment: Are you proposing to list the missing packages? It might be simpler to just cycle over the list and create a report of the missing packages or parse the errors when you try to install something that's missing. Basically, what is the end scenario for this "check" being used?

Comment: I want it to just print out invalid package names. I do it currently using a hack curl of github: https://github.com/pathikrit/mac-setup-script/commit/1a049c28b9344faf07bf2fea908b9cd58443bb01

Comment: Why not just attempt the install and report failure if the return code isn't 0? What does pre-determining get you that attempting to install and detecting failure doesn't?

Comment: Usually package names get outdated or renamed (e.g. `htop` got renamed to `htop-osx`). I would rather fix them all and hit install and forget about it rather than fix failuers at end and edit script by commenting out passed ones and running again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a list of invalid brew formulas:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for formula in ${brews[@]}; do
    brew info ${formula} >/dev/null 2>&1 || echo ${formula}
done
```

To get a list of invalid casks:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for cask in ${casks[@]}; do
    brew cask info ${cask} >/dev/null 2>&1 || echo ${cask}
done
```

(`brews` and `casks` are the arrays defined in your setup script.)

Comment: This does not work since info does a substring search. For example, you can have an invalid package name e.g. `brew info htop` would exit with code 0 but it actually won't work if you try to install it because the actual package name is `htop-osx`.

Comment: @wrick No, `brew install htop` works just fine and installs `htop-osx`. There's an alias defined for `htop`: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Aliases/htop `brew info htop` works because of the aforementioned alias. If you try `brew info hto` then you would get an error. `brew info` doesn't do substring search; `brew search` (contrib) does.